# What is the relation between migration and model?

Tags: laravel

I have created a model `php artisan make:model CommentOnPost` and I want to create it's migration file what name of migration should I use?
Is it correct to be  `php artisan make:migration create_comment_on_posts_table`????

Comment: You can name them anything you like

Comment: i want the migration file to be related to the model file so don't they have a specific name convention ?? like :if model name is (user)then migration file is(users)?

Answer (score 0):

You can create `migration` file with the `model` too.

`php artisan make:model CommentOnPost -m` --> Migration, Model file create with this command

**additional**

`php artisan make:migration create_comment_on_posts_table --create=comment_on_posts` //create only Migration file

`php artisan make:model CommentOnPost -mcr` //For Create `Migration`,`Model`,`Controller` file

Comment: i want to create the migration file and model file separately. if the migration file is named : comment_on_posts then the model name is : CommentOnPost? right?